# CF11 cfgrid Firefox 35 Relative positioning of table rows and Firebug error

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug, coldfusion-11

This has been reported before but not with current Version of CF11 Update 3 and Firefox 35.0. Using Firebug creates a long delay and brings up the warning:

Relative positioning of table rows and row groups is now supported. This site may need to be updated because it may depend on this feature having no effect.
http://localhost/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/ext/ext-all.js
Line 18

Is there any way to get rid of the delay?

Comment: Is it faster when you disable the [*Script* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel)? Note that there are already two bugs reported about slowness in Firebug: [issue 7545](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=7545) and [issue 7721](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=7721).

Comment: Much quicker - as noted in first post it has been reported before but for earlier versions and I believe it was fixed in those

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in Firebug 2.0, which is causing the delay. See [issue 7545](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=7545). This problem is seen on pages making heavy use of JavaScript.

There is also the related [issue 7721](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=7721), which asks to limit the number of dynamically evaluated scripts being displayed within the Location Menu within the [*Script* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel) to avoid slowdowns.

The message you mention, which is probably listed within the *Console* panel, sounds rather unrelated to the delay.